# How to get iOS 6 podcast app to resume the last played podcast

Tags: podcasts, ios, podcasts.app

Ever since upgrading to iOS 6 if I stop in the middle of listening to a podcast and a few hours later start playing using the lock screen buttons, the double-home-and-scroll-left buttons or a physical play button that connects to the iPhone (that I use while driving) one of two things happen:

1. The podcast app starts playing a completely different podcast (always the same one, even if it's already played, I guess it's because it's the most recent podcast in the entire library)
2. The music app starts playing music

Is there any way to get the new smart dedicated podcast app to remember where it left off like the old music app that is obviously not suitable for podcasts because it always worked perfectly?

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a podcast app that just works?

Answer (score 2):

If you run enough other apps for Podcasts to be unloaded from memory, resuming from the lock screen will start playing the Music app.  There's no way around it.  The only thing you can do for now is to delete the Podcasts app so you can play from Music again (after quitting and restarting it), and join the thousands of other people giving it 1 star in iTunes.